# (React Developer Tools) No results in the search bar

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I'm trying to find out the number of messages in a chat, and every guide I've looked up says I need to type `MessengerDetailView` into the search bar, but I don't get any results. Is it because I'm on Mac?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The searchbar you are using, looks for `MessengerDetailView`. If your component has a different name, you won't be able to find it under that name.